# Add 7 days to delivery date

Tags: email, date

I want to add delivery data to order emails which will be 7 days after the order is created. 
   Inside `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::getCreatedAtFormated()` function, following code returns order created date like `November 29, 2015 7:04:52 PM IST`

```
Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($this->getCreatedAtStoreDate(), $format, true);
```

If I'm using `Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($this->getCreatedAtStoreDate()+(7*24*60*60), $format, true);`, it's not returning correct result.

Comment: Can you include what it is returning?

Comment: @SanderMangel: sorry, it returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get order date with:

```
$date = Mage::app()->getLocale()->storeDate(
    $order->getStore(),
    Varien_Date::toTimestamp($order->getCreatedAt()) + (7*24*60*60),
    true,
    $format
);
```

Where `$format` is optional.

Assuming that the `$order` is `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` instance, the `$date` is `Zend_Date` instance which could be easily casted to string.

Answer (score 0):

Need an customer email from the last 7 days through the created date